# How to convert JSON date to MMM yyyy format

Tags: json, date, kendo-grid

I am getting a JSON data like /Date(1588357800000)/. I want to bind this in KendoGrid. How i can Convert this to MMMM yyyy format like May 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved like this:

```
template :#= kendo.toString(new Date(parseInt(dateOfBirth)), 'MMMM yyyy')#"
```

PS: Replace dateOfBirth with 1588357800000

Comment: It is coming with date and time like this :
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)